# Strange discrepancy with tiered pricing percentages

Tags: magento-1.7

Bit stumped by this so reaching out here. Got asked a question by a client - they had a product retailing at 11.40. They added tiered pricing, so if you bought 10 you got 5% off, so the price was then 10.83. But, Magento is displaying a notice that the discount is 6%:

[image: Product at 11.40]

I've experimented with different prices (adding a tiered price of the original minus 5% each time), and it seems that *between* 11.27 and 11.41 the discount is shown as 6%, but anything either side of that correctly shows it as 5%:

[image: Product at 11.27]

[image: Product at 11.41]

Anyone any ideas on why that is? Is it a bug?

Also, just to note, if you move the decimal points 2 places, so the price is 1140 and the tiered price is 1083, it shows as 5%:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well...welcome to PHP.
This in not actually a Magento error. It's more of a PHP error.
I tested with your numbers and I got the same result.
I narrowed the problem to this: 
`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price::getTierPrices()`. to be more precise this line:

```
$price['savePercent'] = ceil(100 - ((100 / $productPrice) * $price['price']));
```

For some reason, this evaluates to 6 even if `100 - ((100/11.4000) * 10.8300)` equals **exactly 5**.
I think it is something similar to the fact that this simple php line:

```
echo (36.001 - 36)
```

Instead of showing `0.001` as we've learned in school, it shows `0.00099999999999767`
and

```
echo (4.001 - 4)
```

shows `0.0010000000000003`. So the error is not even consistent.

Here is a workaround for your issue, but test it first with various values.
The main idea behind it is to work everything in `int` values, and since magento uses 4 decimal places for prices I multiplied everything with 10000 and separated it on 2 lines so it can be read a little easier.
Instead of

```
$price['savePercent'] = ceil(100 - ((100 / $productPrice) * $price['price']));
```

Use this:

```
$value = (int)((1000000 / ($productPrice * 10000)) * $price['price'] * 10000);
$price['savePercent'] = ceil((1000000 - $value) / 10000);
```

I'm not sure that it's a fix of the issue but it worked for me with your numbers.

Comment: Great, seems to be working so far, if anything comes up with it I'll post back...

Answer (score 1):

Changing:
$price['savePercent'] = ceil(100 - ((100 / $productPrice) * $price['price']));

To:
$price['savePercent'] = round(100 - ((100 / $productPrice) * $price['price']), 2);

Will give you the percentage to 2 decimal places, note that I also changed ceil to round.

Also make sure that you Flush Magento Cache or have caching disabled to see correct results.